# $f \star (g \,* \,h) = (f \star g) * h$?

Tags: convolution, cross-correlation

In this paper that I'm reading, I see this equation:
$$S_0 \star (S_0 * N) = N,$$
where $\star$ denotes cross-correlation, $*$ denotes convolution and $S_0 \star S_0 = \delta$. Is it true in general that $f \star (g*h) = (f \star g)*h$ and if not, why is it true here?

Comment: Please explain what $\delta$ means. As to the general result, try to use the frequency domain where convolutions become products and crossscoorelations become dot products to see if the result holds.

Comment: Does [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-correlation#Properties_2) help?

Comment: $\delta$ denotes the Dirac delta.

Answer (score 1):

It's easiest to look at this in the frequency domain. We have
$$\mathcal{F} (x*y) = X \cdot Y$$
$$\mathcal{F} (x \star y) = X' \cdot Y$$
where ' is the complex conjugate

So we get
$$\mathcal{F} (f \star (g * h)) = F' \cdot G \cdot H $$
$$\mathcal{F} ((f \star g) * h) = (F \cdot G)' \cdot H = F' \cdot G' \cdot H  $$

These are only identical if G is real.

In your case you let's simplify the notation to $f = S_0, g = S_0, h = H$ $S_0$ has a unit impulse as autocorrelation, which means that the spectrum of the autocorrelation is just unity, i.e. $1$

$$\mathcal{F} (f \star f) = \mathcal{F} (\delta) = 1 = F' \cdot F$$

We use that property and can show that

$$\mathcal{F} (f \star (f * h)) = F' \cdot F \cdot H = H$$
since $F' \cdot F = 1$

Answer (score 0):

The equation requires that pairwise product are well defined. If so, cross-correlation can be rewritten as a convolution with one function conjugated and time-reversed:

$$a(t) \star b(t) =  a(t) \ast\overline{b}(-t)  =  \overline{a}(-t) \ast b(t) \,.$$

Hence, using associativity of the convolution (or $a\ast b)\ast c = a\ast (b\ast c)$): $$S_0 \star (S_0 \ast N) = \overline{S_0}(-t) \ast (S_0 \ast N) =  (\overline{S_0}(-t) \ast S_0 )\ast N = (S_0 \star S_0 )\ast N\,.$$

This is for instance used in seismic: instead of analyzing the subsurface with something mimicking an impulse (like dynamite), which should be avoided for several reasons, one may use [seismic sources called seismic vibrators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seismic_source#Seismic_vibrator) which:

> propagate energy signals into the Earth over an extended period of
> time as opposed to the near instantaneous energy provided by impulsive
> sources.

They typically are sweeps (similar to chirps) covering a wide range of frequency. The sweep-shaped source signal was generated by controlled vibrations whose autocorrelation is Dirac-like. The data recorded (seismic trace) has then to be cross-correlated with the pilot to yield an impulse response.

The [autocorrelation of two such sweeps is sometimes called a Klauder wavelet](https://wiki.seg.org/wiki/Dictionary:Klauder_wavelet). Some more history in [Vibroseis deconvolution: a synthetic comparison of cross correlation and frequency domain sweep deconvolution](https://www.crewes.org/ForOurSponsors/ResearchReports/2000/2000-19.pdf).